# Need to resize div according to image size before showing the image into it

Tags: jquery

Suppose I have div with fixed height & width. When user click on button then I want load image and put the image in div. Before putting the image into div I want to resize div height & width according to image size with some smooth effect like http://visuallightbox.com/.

When user click on any image there then a div appear and its height & width gets bigger with smooth animation effect. So I want to do the same smooth div growing effect before showing the image into div....how to achieve it. plzz guide.

I know that how to resize div easily like...here is pseudo code:

```
var h=$('#img1').height();
var w=$('#img1').width();
$('div.myGallery').css('width', w + 'px');
$('div.myGallery').css('height', h + 'px');
```

but the problem is that right logic is not coming to mind to show the div with growing effect like visual lightbox plug in. Please guide me with code....thanks

Answer (score 0):

This will animate your div as it grows.

```
$('div.myGallery').animate({
    width: w + 'px',
    height: h + 'px'
});
```

For more information, refer to http://api.jquery.com/animate/.

Comment: first go to http://visuallightbox.com/ site and see the effect how they re-size div with smooth effect and then answer me that how to achieve that smooth effect when div grows.